# Return 0 when SELECT COUNT is null

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this query

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions, COUNT(j.markerid) as marker_jingles
    FROM markers AS m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jingles AS j
    ON j.markerid=m.id
    WHERE 1
```

But am a bit stuck because I cannot figure out how to get it to return rows when the COUNT is 0.

Sincere thanks for the help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your query needs a `GROUP BY` clause, otherwise it will always return only one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want a `group by` in the query?

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions, COUNT(j.markerid) as marker_jingles
FROM markers AS m LEFT OUTER JOIN
     jingles AS j
     ON j.markerid=m.id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Your original query should always return one row, with the count of all matches after the join.  The `count()` value should not be `NULL` -- unless you are using a very old version of MySQL.

Comment: sorry, yeah, count wasn't null but I assumed it was because rows weren't returned.

Comment: I would fully specify the GROUP BY and never rely on the "extension" that MySQL so inconveniently supplies by default. i.e. `GROUP BY m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions`

Comment: @Used_By_Already . . . The use of a unique id in a group by to pull in other columns is *not* an extension (note: I am assuming that `id` is unique) .  ANSI SQL has a concept of "functional dependency".  This basically means that a unique `id` used in a `group by` can bring in other columns from that table.  In other situations, where the functional dependency standard is not met, then this would be an extension.

Answer (score 2):

most dbms platform independent method is use of COALESCE()

```
SELECT
      m.id
    , m.name
    , m.description
    , m.directions
    , COALESCE( COUNT(j.markerid), 0) as marker_jingles
FROM markers AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN jingles AS j ON j.markerid = m.id
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions
```

otherwise IFNULL() works for this need in MySQL

---

- ISNULL() for MS SQL Server, or COALESCE()
- NVL() for Oracle, or COALESCE()
- and so on

COALESCE() is the real friend :)

Comment: thanks a lot, that was my initial idea but hadn't seen coalesce used with COUNT before, only SUM

Comment: you probably don't need it, but you can. COUNT() should return 0 by itself in that query (untested assertion, from old memory).

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function [`COUNT()`] always returns a number. And there is no reason it would ever return `NULL`. `NULL` means *"unknown"*. How could a number of rows be unknown?

Comment: the problem was I wasn't grouping the answers... see @Gordon Linoff answer below

Comment: @ambe5960 that's right. And you don't need `WHERE 1`, it's a no-op.

Comment: @Used_By_Already does `COUNT()` return `NULL` on `SQL Server` or `Oracle`?

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
IFNULL(expr1,expr2)
```

From the documentation:

> If expr1 is not NULL, IFNULL() returns expr1; otherwise it returns
>   expr2. IFNULL() returns a numeric or string value, depending on the
>   context in which it is used.

Comment: How do you suggest to use it in this query?

Comment: @axiac Whats about if `IFNULL((COUNT(j.markerid)), 0)`?

Comment: It's useless. The documentation of [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) MySQL function clearly says *"The result is a `BIGINT` value. `COUNT()` returns `0` if there were no matching rows. "*

Comment: @axiac In some way, the question says `COUNT()` returns `null`. Maybe an old version, as @Gordon already said in his solution.

Answer (score -1):

No need for a left join here, just do a correlated sub-query to get the count:

```
SELECT 
    m.id, m.name, m.description, m.directions,
    (select COUNT(*) 
     from jingles j
     where m.id = j.markerid) as marker_jingles
FROM markers AS m
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Excuse me for asking, but downvoter please explain why! If I'm told how it doesn't work I can edit... But now I don't know what's wrong...